# JQuery accordion with some content shown on all divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Im trying to create an accordion which displays one row of content above before it is expanded.

like so:

```
________________
HEADER ONE    v   - expanded first tab
________________

[  ][  ][  ][  ]  - first row content
[  ][  ][  ][  ]  - second row content
[  ][  ][  ][  ]  - third row content
________________
HEADER TWO    <   - closed first tab
________________
[  ][  ][  ][  ]  - first row shows content
________________
HEADER THREE  <   - closed second tab
________________
[  ][  ][  ][  ]  - first row shows content
```

once the user clicks the corresponding header it will reveal more content underneath, still causing all other content to hide apart from the first single row.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1 class="header">HEADER 01</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="viewable">
            <li>content 01</li>
            <li>content 02</li>
            <li>content 03</li>
            <li>content 04</li>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
            <li>content 05</li>
            <li>content 06</li>
            <li>content 07</li>
            <li>content 08</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
    var $heading = $('.header');
    var $content = $('.hidden');

    $heading.first().toggleClass('active').toggleClass('inactive');
    $('.hidden').first().slideDown().toggleClass('show-content');

    $heading.click(function() {
        if($(this).is('.inactive')) {
            $content.slideToggle(200);
        }
        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('inactive');
            $heading.next().slideToggle().toggleClass('show-content');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I eventually want to make this hold wordpress posts so if there is a smarter way to do this that would be great!

EDIT: The code is doing something, but its not doing what I want it to do, it opens and closes random tabs on click. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bc4uD/

Thanks in advanced,

A

Comment: You don't mention if your code works or not, and what's your exact problem... Try `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`

Comment: Just use this plug-in: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @brasofilo What would this change? "jQuery(document).ready(function($)" He already done the same with $(document).ready(function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your biggest mistake was using the global variable `$content` which actually referred to an array of all the content div's.  You need to select just the content for the clicked on heading.  Also, your extensive use of toggle* methods is probably confusing you because you may think it's toggling one way when actually it's toggling the other way.  Using specific method such as `addClass()/removeClass()` and `slideDown()/slideUp()` makes it easier to debug your code and see what's going on. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/Bc4uD/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
        <h1 class="header">HEADER 01</h1>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="viewable">
            <li>content 01</li>
            <li>content 02</li>
            <li>content 03</li>
            <li>content 04</li>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
            <li>content 05</li>
            <li>content 06</li>
            <li>content 07</li>
            <li>content 08</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
        <h1 class="header">HEADER 02</h1>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="viewable">
            <li>content 01</li>
            <li>content 02</li>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
            <li>content 03</li>
            <li>content 04</li>
            <li>content 05</li>
            <li>content 06</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
        <h1 class="header">HEADER 03</h1>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="viewable">
            <li>content 01</li>
            <li>content 02</li>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden">
            <li>content 03</li>
            <li>content 04</li>
            <li>content 05</li>
            <li>content 06</li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $heading = $('.header');
    var $content = $('.hidden');

    $heading.first().addClass('active');
    $('.hidden').first().slideDown(200).addClass('show-content');

    $heading.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), // cache it for performance
            $thisContent = $this.next('.content').find('.hidden');

        if ($this.is('.active')) { // Extra content is showing so hide it
            $thisContent.slideUp(200).removeClass('show-content');
            $this.removeClass('active');
        } else { // Extra content is hidden so show it
            $thisContent.slideDown(200).addClass('show-content');
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here go

http://plnkr.co/edit/zAvdJ7SG8TmMEgDCKmrh

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var heading = document.getElementsByClassName('header');
  $('.hidden').hide();
  $(heading).attr('data-content', ' >');
  $(heading).click(function() {
    elem = this;
    $('.hidden').each(function(i) {
      if (elem.innerHTML == heading.item(i).innerHTML) {
        if (this.style.display == 'block') {
          $(this).slideUp();
          $(heading.item(i)).attr('data-content', ' >');
        } else {
          $(this).slideDown();
          $(heading.item(i)).attr('data-content', ' <');
        }
      } else {
        $(this).slideUp();
        $(heading.item(i)).attr('data-content', ' >');
      }
    });
  });
});
```